# Run only selected file from right-click context menu with batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

Simple batch file e.g.

```
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
    start notepad.exe "%%~ni.txt"
)
```

Run it through right-click context menu as answered [here](https://superuser.com/a/1070913/306306)

It works correctly as long as there's only one .txt file in the directory. If there are multiple .txt  files, it opens all of them.

How to open only the one file that was right-clicked on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why `%%~ni.txt` is used when you can just do `%%~i`, anyway, this should only use the first item in the input:

```
@echo off
for %%i in ("%~1") do (
    start notepad.exe "%%~i"
)
```

Though, much simpler would be to replace everything above with this one line:

```
@start "" notepad.exe "%~1"
```